# Необходимо создать ещё один файл в проекте и туда перенести определённый код из другого файла python

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, sqlite, pyqt

Класс `Lodgers` перенести в новый файл **GetRooms.py**. 
В этом классе надо запомнить `model`, а `tableView_1` не в нем, а в окне.

Также нужно прочитать записи в список или сразу в методе `getRooms` сделать обход модели и вычисление занятых мест. 
Этот метод отлаживается отдельно (можно напечатать полученный список), а потом только связывать с графикой.

**main.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import mainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
from RoomWindow import Ui_RoomWindow
from lodgers import Ui_lodgers


# новый класс
class Lodgers(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_lodgers):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Lodgers, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza.db')
        sdb.open()
        model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)
        model.setTable("users")
        model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        model.select()

        self.tableView_1.setModel(model)


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.openRoomWindow)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.openlodgers)
        # Функция закрытия главного окна по кнопке Выход
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("section_sketch.png"))
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.drowRooms)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.lodgers = Lodgers()
        self.lodgers.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow1)

        self.rоом_beds = []
        self.rоом_rect = {
            '131': 0,
            '132': 1,
            '133': 2,
            '134': 3,
            '135': 4,
            '136': 5,
            '137': 6,
            '138': 7,
        }

    # Метод для отрисовки
    def drowRooms(self):
        self.Rooms = []
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 131 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя через список)
            self.scene.addRect(195, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1311
            self.scene.addRect(240, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1312
            self.scene.addRect(195, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1313
            self.scene.addRect(240, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1314
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 132 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(330, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1321
            self.scene.addRect(375, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1322
            self.scene.addRect(330, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1323
            self.scene.addRect(375, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1324
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 133 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(465, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1331
            self.scene.addRect(510, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1332
            self.scene.addRect(465, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1333
            self.scene.addRect(510, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1334
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 134 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(595, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1341
            self.scene.addRect(640, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1342
            self.scene.addRect(595, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1343
            self.scene.addRect(640, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1344
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 135 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(595, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1351
            self.scene.addRect(640, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1352
            self.scene.addRect(595, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1353
            self.scene.addRect(640, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1354
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 136 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(465, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1361
            self.scene.addRect(510, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1362
            self.scene.addRect(465, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1363
            self.scene.addRect(510, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1364
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 137 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(330, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1371
            self.scene.addRect(375, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1372
            self.scene.addRect(330, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1373
            self.scene.addRect(375, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1374
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 138 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(195, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1381
            self.scene.addRect(240, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1382
            self.scene.addRect(195, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1383
            self.scene.addRect(240, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1384

        self.rоом_beds = []
        model = self.lodgers.tableView_1.model()
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            if model.data(model.index(row, 2)) == 1:
                rоом_bed = str(model.data(model.index(row, 1)))[:3], str(model.data(model.index(row, 1)))[3]
                self.rоом_beds.append(rоом_bed)

        for k, v in self.rоом_beds:
            self.Rooms[self.rоом_rect[k]][int(v)].setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(Qt.red))

    # Функция перехода на окно Комнаты
    def openRoomWindow(self):
        self.RoomWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_RoomWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self.RoomWindow)
        ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow)
        self.hide()  # для сворачивания предыдущего окна
        self.RoomWindow.show()

    def openlodgers(self):
        self.lodgers = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_lodgers()
        ui.setupUi(self.lodgers)
        ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow1)
        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza.db')
        sdb.open()
        model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)
        model.setTable("users")
        model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        model.select()
        ui.tableView_1.setModel(model)

        self.hide()  # для сворачивания предыдущего окна
        self.lodgers.show()

    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна комнаты) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow(self):
        self.RoomWindow.close()
        self.show()

    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна проживающие) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow1(self):
        self.lodgers.close()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**mainWindow.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1087, 593)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Просмотр Плана Секции")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(900, 530, 161, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 164, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 280, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 220, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 775, 535))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        '''''
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 0, 71, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        '''''

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(495, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(625, 17, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")


        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(625, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")

        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(495, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")

        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_7.setFont(font)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")

        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 440, 105, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выход"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комнаты"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Просмотр"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проживающие"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 131"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 132"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 133"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 134"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 135"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 136"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 137"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комната 138"))
```

**RoomWindow.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_RoomWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, RoomWindow):
        RoomWindow.setObjectName("RoomWindow")
        RoomWindow.resize(1087, 593)
        RoomWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        RoomWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(RoomWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_6.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 551, 411))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        RoomWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(RoomWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(RoomWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, RoomWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        RoomWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("RoomWindow", "Комнаты"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("RoomWindow", "Назад"))
```

**lodgers.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_lodgers(object):
    def setupUi(self, lodgers):
        lodgers.setObjectName("lodgers")
        lodgers.resize(1087, 593)
        lodgers.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        lodgers.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1087, 593))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(lodgers)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 530, 209, 40))
        self.pushButton_8.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("font: 75 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.tableView_1 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 551, 411))
        self.tableView_1.setObjectName("tableView_1")
        lodgers.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(lodgers)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(lodgers)

    def retranslateUi(self, lodgers):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        lodgers.setWindowTitle(_translate("lodgers", "Проживающие"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("lodgers", "Назад"))
```

Comment: Это вы задание набросали для участников сообщества?

Comment: просто у меня по курсовой задание, а я не особо улавливаю питон вообще

Comment: спать пока не ложитесь, сейчас гляну что вы там придумали.

Comment: хорошо жду, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я отметил для вас строки. в которые внес изменения. Публикую только измененные модули.

**main.py**

```
import sys
#- import mainWindow
from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow                             # Ui_MainWindow

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel

from RoomWindow import Ui_RoomWindow
#- from lodgers import Ui_lodgers


# новый класс
from GetRooms import Lodgers                                              # +++
'''
class Lodgers(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_lodgers):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Lodgers, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza_1214255.db')                            # baza.db
        sdb.open()
        model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)
        model.setTable("users")
        model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        model.select()

        self.tableView_1.setModel(model)
'''

#class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                    # Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.setupUi(self)
#+++ vvv       
        self.lodgers = Lodgers()                                           # !!!
        self.lodgers.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow1)

        self.rоом_beds = []
        self.rоом_rect = {
            '131': 0,
            '132': 1,
            '133': 2,
            '134': 3,
            '135': 4,
            '136': 5,
            '137': 6,
            '138': 7,
        }       
#+++ ^^^        
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.openRoomWindow)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.openlodgers)        
        # Функция закрытия главного окна по кнопке Выход
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.scene.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"))     # section_sketch.png установите свое !!!
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.drowRooms)
       
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)

        ''' пуренес выше !!!  
        self.lodgers = Lodgers()
        self.lodgers.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow1)

        self.rоом_beds = []
        self.rоом_rect = {
            '131': 0,
            '132': 1,
            '133': 2,
            '134': 3,
            '135': 4,
            '136': 5,
            '137': 6,
            '138': 7,
        }
        '''

    # Метод для отрисовки
    def drowRooms(self):
        if not self.lodgers.rоом_beds:                                      # +++
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Message', 
                f'Просматривать рановать. \n'
                f'Нажмите кнопку `Проживающие` и выполните необходимые корректировки.'
            )
            return
    
        self.Rooms = []
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 131 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя через список)
            self.scene.addRect(195, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1311
            self.scene.addRect(240, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1312
            self.scene.addRect(195, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1313
            self.scene.addRect(240, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1314
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 132 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(330, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1321
            self.scene.addRect(375, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1322
            self.scene.addRect(330, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1323
            self.scene.addRect(375, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1324
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 133 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(465, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1331
            self.scene.addRect(510, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1332
            self.scene.addRect(465, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1333
            self.scene.addRect(510, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1334
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 134 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(595, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1341
            self.scene.addRect(640, 40, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1342
            self.scene.addRect(595, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1343
            self.scene.addRect(640, 85, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1344
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 135 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(595, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1351
            self.scene.addRect(640, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1352
            self.scene.addRect(595, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1353
            self.scene.addRect(640, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1354
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 136 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(465, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1361
            self.scene.addRect(510, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1362
            self.scene.addRect(465, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1363
            self.scene.addRect(510, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1364
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 137 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(330, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1371
            self.scene.addRect(375, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1372
            self.scene.addRect(330, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1373
            self.scene.addRect(375, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1374
        self.Rooms.append((
            # Рисование прямоугольников для 138 комнаты (обозначения для того чтобы в дальнеёшем присвоить прямоугольникам имя)
            self.scene.addRect(195, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1381
            self.scene.addRect(240, 320, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1382
            self.scene.addRect(195, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green)),  # 1383
            self.scene.addRect(240, 365, 35, 35, pen=QtGui.QPen(Qt.black), brush=QtGui.QBrush(Qt.green))))  # 1384

        ''' перенес в новый класс !!!
        self.rоом_beds = []
        model = self.lodgers.tableView_1.model()
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            if model.data(model.index(row, 2)) == 1:
                rоом_bed = str(model.data(model.index(row, 1)))[:3], str(model.data(model.index(row, 1)))[3]
                self.rоом_beds.append(rоом_bed)
        '''
        #           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <-- список сформированный в новом классе
        for k, v in self.lodgers.rоом_beds:     # - self.rоом_beds;   + self.lodgers.rоом_beds  
            self.Rooms[self.rоом_rect[k]][int(v)].setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(Qt.red))

    # Функция перехода на окно Комнаты
    def openRoomWindow(self):
        self.RoomWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_RoomWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self.RoomWindow)
        ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow)
        self.hide()  # для сворачивания предыдущего окна
        self.RoomWindow.show()

    def openlodgers(self):
        ''' это не нужно вообще
        self.lodgers = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_lodgers()
        ui.setupUi(self.lodgers)
        ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.returnMainWindow1)
        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza_1214255.db')                        # baza.db
        sdb.open()
        model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)
        model.setTable("users")
        model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        model.select()
        ui.tableView_1.setModel(model)
        '''
        self.hide()  
        self.lodgers.show()

    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна комнаты) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow(self):
        self.RoomWindow.close()
        self.show()

    # Функция для возвращения на главное окно (Из окна проживающие) по кнопке Назад
    def returnMainWindow1(self):
        self.lodgers._getRooms()                    # ВНИМАНИЕ, список self.lodgers.rоом_beds
        #print("222 ", self.lodgers.rоом_beds)      # формируетс здесь
        self.drowRooms()                            # и сразу вызывается отрисовка !!!
    
        self.lodgers.close()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**GetRooms.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlTableModel
from lodgers import Ui_lodgers                                    # +


# новый класс
class Lodgers(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_lodgers):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Lodgers, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        sdb = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        sdb.setDatabaseName('baza_1214255.db')                    # baza.db замените на свою
        sdb.open()
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(db=sdb)                       # + self.model атрибут класса
        self.model.setTable("users")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.model.select()

        self.tableView_1.setModel(self.model)
        
        self.rоом_beds = []                                       # +++
        
    def _getRooms(self):                                          # +++
        self.rоом_beds = []                                       # +++
        for row in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            if self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 2)) == 1:    # + self.model атрибут класса
                rоом_bed = str( self.model.data(
                                   self.model.index(row, 1)))[:3], \
                           str(self.model.data(self.model.index(row, 1)))[3]
                self.rоом_beds.append(rоом_bed)
                
        # print(self.rоом_beds)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое всё правильно.